# Azure platform Cannot access to Public IP port

Tags: ubuntu, networking, azure

I'm new to Azure platform. I'm setting up two machines, one for Database, one for Application. both are Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. They are both set up with resource manager ( because if I set up them with classic method, I cannot set a virtual network, they became publicly availailable )

They are both in the same virtual network, connected with network interfaces in the same subnet. Application server has a public IP address. Database server is hidden in the virtual network.

I've forwarded my domain from DNS to application servers's public ip, which has a simple nginx server. I've set the network service gateway inbound and outbound rules for ports 22,80 and 443 (ssh, http and https respectively).

I can access my server from shell like

```
ssh username@domain.com
```

but when I try it on my browser, or make a telnet like

```
telnet domain.com 80
```

There's no way that I can access the server. Nginx logs **tcpdump** command is not showing anything.

I've checked **ifconfig**, it only shows the private address which is in subnet by using the **eth0** interface, there's nothing for the public ip address.

I'm kinda stuck out for trying solutions out. Anybody with experience?

PS: There's no cloud service running for application server, because it's created with resource manager. But still, I shouldn't be able to connect via ssh right?

EDİT: Here are the inbound and outbound rules;
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I had to set the inbound http and https traffic source port to * instead of 80 and 443. Now it works like a charm.

Comment: That is because in a TCP connection, the source port is usually random regardless of the destination port.